# Using Limit with group_contact in MySQL 5

Tags: mysql, limit, group-concat

Good morning guys, I have a question:

I have the following sample SQL:

```
group_concat( DISTINCT `mvu5877_anuncios_photos`.`image` ORDER BY `mvu5877_anuncios_photos`.`order` ASC SEPARATOR ',' ) AS `images`
```

In SEPARATOR I need to define a quantity instead of bringing all the items. In MariaDB I can do this just past the Limit at the end. Example:

```
group_concat( DISTINCT `mvu5877_anuncios_photos`.`image` ORDER BY `mvu5877_anuncios_photos`.`order` ASC SEPARATOR ',' LIMIT 4 ) AS `images
```

More in MySQL 5.7.32 the syntax error. Any suggestion?

Comment: In MySQL 8.x you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in a subquery to limit the entries per group. In the latest version you can also use lateral queries for the same purpose.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: I managed to solve it. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) so that you get the top 4 values in the results:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `mvu5877_anuncios_photos`.`image` ORDER BY `mvu5877_anuncios_photos`.`order`),
  ',',
  4
)
```

Comment: I believe this was a simpler way to resolve it. It worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation: [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat). There is no syntax for a LIMIT keyword inside a GROUP_CONCAT() call. This is a feature specific to MariaDB, [introduced in MariaDB 10.3.3](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11297).

In MySQL 5.7, you would have to use a subquery to limit the results, then use GROUP_CONCAT() in the outer query:

```
mysql> select  group_concat( DISTINCT `image` ORDER BY `order` ASC SEPARATOR ',' ) AS `images` 
  from mytable;
+-----------------+
| images          |
+-----------------+
| abc,def,ghi,jkl |
+-----------------+

mysql> select group_concat( DISTINCT `image` ORDER BY `order` ASC SEPARATOR ',' ) AS `images` 
  from (select * from mytable limit 2) as t;
+---------+
| images  |
+---------+
| abc,def |
+---------+
```